# VBA code stopped working normally

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a small VBA program a few days back which was working fine using an assigned button on Quick Access Toolbar and also through an assigned keyboard shortcut. However, sometime earlier today, it has started behaving abnormally. When I run it under debug mode, all lines execute as expected but when I run it through assigned button or keyboard shortcut, it seems has the code is stuck infinitely. I really have no idea what went wrong.

Below is my VBA code:

```
Sub GetLengthOfSelection()

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Selection.Range

On Error Resume Next

LenFinder:
If Len(Rng) >= 43 Then
    GoTo Trimmer
Else
    Set Rng = Selection.Range
    MsgBox Rng, vbInformation
    Rng.Copy
    q = Rng.Words.Count
    Set Rng = Rng.Words(q)
    Rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Rng.MoveEndUntil CSET:=Chr(13), Count:=wdForward

    If Len(Rng) >= 43 Then
        GoTo Trimmer
    End If

    MsgBox Rng, vbInformation, "Text after new range definition"
    Rng.Copy
    Exit Sub
End If

Trimmer:
Rng.MoveEnd wdWord, -1
Rng.Select
Set Rng = Selection.Range
GoTo LenFinder

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the On Error Resume Next and see if an error is reported.

Comment: Also get rid of the GoTo+label commands, they are a very very bad practice. Structure your program properly using branches, loops and subroutines.

Comment: Precisely because of these idiotic goto commands (not you, the command itself is idiotic) you can't see, but this is actually an endless loop. It just never ends, just keeps going back to the beginning of the code and redoes everything again and again. Just structure your program properly. Read some theory or talk to a programmer or something. :)

Comment: Vacip, I value your advice but the only thing which is still intriguing me is the fact that I ran this small code a hundred times in last few days without having any problem. The program was able to quit the subroutine/procedure through "Exit Sub" as soon as code encountered a line break on selected text within Word document. Could you please run this code on your machine and let me know if you also face this problem or not. I can recall that I got a digital ID requirement earlier today and suspect something went wrong during my attempt to use the SELFCERT.exe file.

Comment: If what you have selected is very long, or something is in the selection that doesn't react to MoveEnd, your code will have problems. Possibly you never encountered that situation before.

Comment: Cindy, I used MoveEnd method for the first time myself. I am more accustomed to Excel VBA, but I hope I will get a clue.